# Xcode build with Jenkins on Yosemite agvtool not working

Tags: xcode, jenkins, osx-yosemite, agvtool

Yesterday I updated my Jenkins server to Yosemite due to various issues and now my builds which were using the agvtool to set the build number / marketing version for applications are no longer updating the build number / marketing version correctly. I have the command line tools installed, I get no errors or warnings when building a project, the version number is just not updated.

This was working fine until I updated my build server to Yosemite.